# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{n!}{1\cdot 3 \cdot \cdots \cdot (2n-1)} 2^n= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{4^n n! n!}{(2n)!}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I am trying to compute the interval of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{n!}{1\cdot 3 \cdot \cdots \cdot (2n-1)} x^{2n+1}$. Letting $a_n= \dfrac{n!}{1\cdot 3 \cdot \cdots \cdot (2n-1)} x^{2n+1}$, we have $\lim_{n\to \infty} |a_{n+1}/a_n|= x^2/2$, so the radius of convergence is $\sqrt{2}$. What I only need to check now is that checking the convergence of the series above when $x=\pm \sqrt{2}$. Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{n!}{1\cdot 3 \cdot \cdots \cdot (2n-1)} \sqrt{2}^{2n+1}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{n!}{1\cdot 3 \cdot \cdots \cdot (2n-1)} (-\sqrt{2})^{2n+1}$, I only need to consider the case $x=\sqrt{2}$. In the case $x=\sqrt{2}$, the series is given by $\sqrt{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{n!}{1\cdot 3 \cdot \cdots \cdot (2n-1)} 2^n= \sqrt{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{4^n n! n!}{(2n)!}$, but I can't see whether or not this series converges. Any hints?

Comment: Apply Stirling's Formula.

Comment: what is $x$ in your question?

Comment: Look up estimates for the Central Binomial Coefficients, $$\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient

Comment: Applying Stirling's Formula shows that $$\frac{4^n (n!)^2}{(2n)!}\sim \frac{4^n(2\pi n)(n/e)^{2n}}{\sqrt{4\pi n}(2n/e)^{2n}}=O(\sqrt n)$$

Comment: So much abuse of `\dfrac`...

Comment: You may be interested in this paper, http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/g27/g27.pdf

Answer (score 1):

One more, possibly easier, way to use estimation:

$$\sqrt{2n} \lt  \frac{2}{1}\cdot\frac{4}{3}\cdot \frac{6}{5}\cdots \frac{2n}{2n-1} \leqslant 2\sqrt{n}$$